# Linear Elliptic Problems: Are gradient estimates preserved after perturbation?

Tags: perturbation-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

We start with the linear elliptic PDE

$$
-\operatorname{div}(A\nabla u)=f \quad\text{in}\ \Omega,\\
u=0 \quad\text{on}\ \partial\Omega
$$
We assume that $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth domain, $A\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is bounded and positive definite matrix-valued function (there is $c_A>0$ such that $A\xi\cdot\xi>c_\alpha|\xi|^2$ for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^3$), and a function $f\in L^s(\Omega)$ for some $s>2$.

For some $\delta>0$ and some continuous $B\colon\overline{\Omega}\to\mathbb{R}^3$, we also look at the perturbed problem

$$
-\operatorname{div}((A+\delta B)\nabla v)=f \quad\text{in}\ \Omega,\\
v=0 \quad\text{on}\ \partial\Omega.
$$

My question: If I know, that I have bounds on the gradient of $u$, like $\|\nabla u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leq C(C_P,|\Omega|,c_\alpha,\|f\|_{L^s(\Omega)})$, can I conclude something similar for $v$ (for sufficiently small $\delta$), like

$$
\|\nabla v\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leq C(C_P,|\Omega|,c_\alpha,\|f\|_{L^s(\Omega)},\delta, \|B\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)})?
$$
In these estimates, $C_P$ denotes the Poincare inequality constant.

I tried to prove this estimate via difference quotients and cut-offs but somehow got stuck. If it holds, what technique would you use to prove this? And if it is not possible, why could this estimate fail?